# Count duplicates WHERE id=?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to `SELECT opponents id from a db table WHERE id=$currplayer`.

My DB table is like this:
**fk_player
fk_opponent**

If I do like this:

```
SELECT fk_opponent
     , COUNT(fk_opponent) AS oplay 
FROM nf_newversus 
     GROUP BY fk_opponent
```

It does the thing right, but I want to be able to sort this so it is only the ones where fk_player = $currplayer... I have tried to insert a `WHERE fk_player = $currplayer` but that is not right...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `HAVING fk_player = '$currplayer'`? Doesn't feel right though, because it's not meant to be used for that :)

Comment: `I have tried to insert a WHERE fk_player = $currplayer but [that] is not right...` - in what way does that not work? "not right" is not an error message.

Comment: Sorry... When inserting WHERE I get all the opponents for the current player but not the count. All counts says "1" then?

Answer (score 1):

This should be correct according to your description:

```
SELECT fk_opponent, COUNT(*) AS oplay
FROM nf_newversus 
WHERE fk_player='$currplayer'
GROUP BY fk_opponent
```

If your table allows multiple `player1 vs player2` (i.e. no `UNIQUE(fk_player, fk_opponent)` index), that should work just fine, but **assuming you store matches in both ways**.

Comment: When doing this I only get one record out? I need to get a list of all the oppenents the current user have played against and how many games.

Comment: @JesperMansa Updated the answer, which now looks exactly like @bobwienholt; however, I've added the conditions under which the query would generate the right results.

Comment: It still doesn't do the right thing. When doing this I get all my opponents but only with the count 1.

Comment: @JesperMansa that means you have played one game with each opponent, isn't it?

Comment: Nope... I have played several games with each opponent

Comment: @JesperMansa then the number of games is not stored in this manner

Comment: When I do this on a single opponent like this: SELECT * FROM nf_newversus WHERE fk_player=$playerid AND fk_opponent=$oppid I get numbers like 5, 7 and 11 depending on the opponent?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT fk_opponent
     , COUNT(fk_opponent) AS oplay
FROM nf_newversus 
WHERE fk_player = '$currplayer'
GROUP BY fk_opponent
```